# Child processes are creating a struct in the same memory address

Tags: c, process, shared-memory, consumer, producer

This is the start of my function. I have a parent process that creates multiple child processes that call this producer function. I want each p_shm_recv_buf struct to be unique for the process, when my output of the print statements gives me the exact same memory address. I'm not sure whats going wrong here.

```
int producer( int id, ISTACK * buffer, int BUFFER_SIZE, sem_vars* sems, int image_num ) {
    printf("[Creation] Producer %d created\n", id);
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    while (buffer->next_prod < 50) {

        // Create our receive buffer
        RECV_BUF *p_shm_recv_buf;
        int shm_size = sizeof_shm_recv_buf(BUF_SIZE);
        int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shm_size, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if ( shmid == -1 ) {
            perror("shmget");
            abort();
        }
        printf("[LOG1] buf address at %p\n", p_shm_recv_buf->buf);
        p_shm_recv_buf = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
        printf("[LOG2] buf address at %p\n", p_shm_recv_buf->buf);
        shm_recv_buf_init(p_shm_recv_buf, BUF_SIZE);
```

Output:

```
shm_size = 44.
sem_size = 104.
[Creation] Producer 0 created
[Creation] Producer 1 created
[Creation] Producer 2 created
[Creation] Consumer 5 created
[Creation] Consumer 3 created
[Creation] Consumer 4 created
[LOG1] buf address at 0x7ffefa2d8ca0
[LOG2] buf address at (nil)
[LOG3] buf address at 0x7fe4a879c020
Producer 0 working ... 
[LOG1] buf address at 0x7ffefa2d8ca0
[LOG2] buf address at (nil)
[LOG3] buf address at 0x7fe4a879c020
Producer 1 working ... 
[LOG1] buf address at 0x7ffefa2d8ca0
[LOG2] buf address at (nil)
[LOG3] buf address at 0x7fe4a879c020
```

Comment: Why would this be a problem? Processes doesn't share memory maps, they each have their own memory map.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ah thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

each process has a complete 'virtual' memory map.

and remember that a child process is a copy of the parent process.

so having the same 'virtual' memory address is to be expected